# Why does std::shared_ptr not behave like raw point when assign to another?

Tags: c++, std, smart-pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main () {
std::shared_ptr<int> foo;
std::shared_ptr<int> bar (new int(10));

foo = bar;             
bar.reset(new int(20));

std::cout << "*foo: " << *foo << '\n';
std::cout << "*bar: " << *bar << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

output:
*foo: 10
*bar: 20

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main () {
int * foo;
int *bar = new int(10);

foo = bar;
*bar = 20;

std::cout << "*foo: " << *foo << '\n';
std::cout << "*bar: " << *bar << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

output:
*foo: 20
*bar: 20

How to make shared_pt B from shared_pt A that B has the same inner value as A whatever A change later  (like the above raw pointer example) ?

Comment: The raw-pointer equivalent of `bar.reset(new int(20));` is `bar = new int(20);`, not `*bar = 20;`.

Comment: Or the shared pointer equivalent of `*bar = 20;` is still `*bar = 20;`.

Comment: [RTFM](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/reset/)

Answer (score 3):

They behave the same way if you do the same thing

```
int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<int> foo;
  std::shared_ptr<int> bar(new int(10));

  foo = bar;
  *bar = 20;

  std::cout << "*foo: " << *foo << '\n';
  std::cout << "*bar: " << *bar << '\n';

  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```